# Compile git for /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 from vm that links with /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 by default

Tags: compiling, git, make, gcc, cross-compilation

I'm building git from source from a debian 10 vm that has `/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1`, which ends up linked in the git binary after a basic `NO_TCLTK=true make prefix=$(pwd)/2.41.0/arm make all` and `~ install` from the repository. I intend to run it from the host, but it throws "no such file or directory" error, without telling which file it is referring to exactly, but since `ldd $(pwd)/2.41.0/arm/bin/git` lists only five dependencies:

```
~$ ldd shuttle/git/2.41.0/arm32/bin/git
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000007560d80000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x0000007560972000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000007560941000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00000075607cd000)
        /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000007560d50000)
```

i can tell that it's probably that "/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1", because the host system has only a "/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3" in its place.
"linux-vdso.so.1" is also not located with "whereis", but from that output it looks like it's somehow internal, because it's not found from inside the vm either. So by way of elimination it's got to be that file in /lib.
For more context, the vm is Crostini and the host system is Chrome OS.
Thanks!

Comment: you not only need to *link* differently, you also need to *compile* differently – the way these two architectures handle floating point, and ABI, is different. So, you need to do do a full cross-compilation.

Comment: @MarcusMüller i mean i'm not _linking_ explicitly, it's these 2 _make_ commands that git's INSTALL file instructs. So i'm looking for pointers on how to adjust the compilation or "configure" it in advance.

Comment: okay after copying the ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 over to the host system for test, the next error i get is "error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32" - so it's indeed not just a matter of linking that /lib file, but compiling with "elf32hf" somehow. is that more than just a set of compilation flags?

Comment: Well, it seems you did not understand what I commented. You need to *cross-compile*, i.e. you need to use a compiler that targets the armhf platform. So, you need to figure out how to tell the build system of what you're building (git here) to use a different compiler, and of course you need to start with having that compiler.  Yes, that's simply a different compiler, and not just some flags. The fact that both platforms have something to do with "arm" doesn't mean they are the same.

Comment: apologies for not remembering the difference in approach between compilation and cross-compilation, but i seem to recall it's still done with make, only with adjusted flags for target architecture etc. so your reply hasn't seemed to invalidate my question about changes to the make configuration. if you can specify how questions about compilation with `make` are complletely irrelevant to question about cross-compilation, you will be right to say i didn't understand you. edit: okay you did elaborate in the meantime, thank you

Comment: not flags to make, as said, you need to convince your build system to use a different compiler, so that's flags to ./configure :) The `make` call doesn't usually take any flags.

Comment: i actually have a certain "gnu/gcc/arm64elf32hf/12.2.0/"  and "11.3.0" folder, with content of 
"12.2.rel1-aarch64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf-manifest.txt  arm-none-linux-gnueabihf  bin  include  lib  libexec  share"
from last time i tinkered on this machine, that might be useful. i remember i saved an article about this crosscompilation somewhere too...

Comment: i saved these cryptic instructions there: 
`"binutils":{"git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git":{"binutils-2_40":
["../source/configure --prefix=$HOME/binutils/arm32/2.40 --target=aarch64-none-linux-gnueabihf --with-cpu=cortex-a73 --with-no-thumb-interwork --with-mode=thumb"
,"make all install 2>&1 | tee log"
]}}, 
"gcc":{"git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git":{"12.2.0":
["../source/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc/12.2.0 --host=aarch64-none-linux-gnueabihf --target=aarch64-none-linux-gnueabihf --with-cpu=cortex-a73 --enable-languages='c,c++' --with-no-thumb-interwork --with-mode=thumb"
]}}`

Comment: and here's the article: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/cross-compiling-gcc-toolchain-arm-cortex-m-processors-ijaz-ahmad

Comment: OK, logged in to linked in…

Comment: that article is about building a cross toolchain for Cortex-M. That's not related to what you need to do :)

Comment: yea sorry it's a gated article, i actually had it saved as html for this reason. Well the chip i'm dealing with is a "Mediatek Helio P60t, 12 nm FinFET (12FFC) processor equipped with 4x big ARM Cortex-A73 cores and 4x small and power efficient ARM Cortex-A53 cores in two clusters (bigLITTLE)". "Cortex-M" apparently sounded close enough that i saved that article but idk what i achieved back then. i suppose i need to make 32 instead of 64bit (elf class?), and "hf" instead of whatever (something). a VM can't be so off from a host. as you can tell i'm not the most well versed around this stuff.

Comment: an interesting relevant detail at https://developer.arm.com/Tools%20and%20Software/GNU%20Toolchain : "GNU Toolchain releases from Arm were published previously as two separate releases - one for A-Profile and the other for R-Profile and M-Profile, (GNU Toolchain for A-profile processors and  GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain). Arm GNU Toolchain releases unifies these two into a single release and the previous way of releases therefore have been discontinued. However, the previous releases will continue to be available for reference."

Comment: Cortex-M vs Cortex-A: it's not close enough. Different architectures, different compilers. The fact that arm packages their own compiler in a "dual pack" doesn't make it any more one compiler. It's just installs two compilers. I don't know where the term "VM" suddenly comes from. You need to install an armhf compiler on your Linux system. Very many Linux distros ship one of these. In your case, all you need to do is `apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` to get one. The question really is why you're cross-compiling git for an embedded system? That seems – strange, to begin with.

Comment: the term VM was there from the first sentence in my post (if not the title): "debian 10 vm" (crostini, on chrome os). that probably explains the confusion about "embedded". and why it's curious to me that the vm has a different architecture than the host to begin with. damn that apt install did work actually. now i need to figure out how i instruct make to use that compiler to answer my original question.

Comment: … by giving the right flags to `./configure`, as mentioned above. `./configure --help` might help!

Comment: ./configure --help: Influential env variables:
CC - C compiler command.
CFLAGS - C compiler flags.
LDFLAGS - linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a nonstandard <lib dir>.
LIBS - libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>.
CPPFLAGS - (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if you have headers in a nonstandard <include dir>.
CPP - C preprocessor. 
so the answer to my question would be "CC=/path/to/gcc-gnueabihf make"? why the downvote and acting like this is insanely trivial? it raises 2 questions that don't even fit in this comment box to ask

Comment: the 2 questions being #1 what do i look for as a result of `apt install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` that i need to define as CC? the files i download from the developer.arm.com link i shared give me clues but you dismissed them as irrelevant, only because they package multiple arm compilers together. what's your point?
and #2: is this really satisfactory to fix the 2 errors i encountered: "hf" is present in the title of the crosscompiler (wether apt install or downloaded from the link), but i don't see how it implies a resolution of the "wrong elf class: ELFCLASS32" problem appearing on the host

Comment: and i only assume that the term "hf" being present in the name of the crosscompiler will result in /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 being found on the target (host, with respect to the vm) system.